# jQuery click event working except on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I've encountered an issue that's really just a giant mystery to me.

Check out my Web Design portfolio http://drootech.com, if you notice on a desktop the red "See what else we do." button works fine using the following code on a desktop browser. But the odd thing is it doesn't work on mobile.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#seemore").on('click touchstart', function (){
        //$(this).animate(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#mrkting").offset().top - 85
                 }, 2000);
        //});
    });
```

I have another click/touchstart event is triggering the same scroll destination, is that why it's not working? And if so how would I get around this issue? Here's the other code that may be potential conflictual?

```
 $("#info").on('click touchstart', function (){
        //$(this).animate(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("h2#mrkting").offset().top - 85
                 }, 2000);
            $('#nav-menubg').slideUp('slow');
        //});
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does it work if you have only click event for that specific `$("#seemore")`click?

Comment: Nope. I just commented out the "info" code and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Andrew I meant remove the touchstart, just have the click event. Btw, in your page you have a inline jQuery `onclick` in the `a` element. You have the same in jQuery script, so you can remove the inline one in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML portion of the code, on the elements you want to react when clicked on, add the javascript attribute onclick=""

ie.

```
<tag id="seemore" onclick=""></tag>
```

Comment: onclick="$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".jumbotron").offset().top - 85}, 2000);$('#nav-menubg').slideUp('slow');"

and I tried calling the function onclick too. no such luck :(

Comment: no no, don't put the jquery code inside the onclick function; the onclick needs to be empty quotations. The actual code should be inside a script tag.

Comment: trust me, I had this problem last year. the code looked perfect, and I couldn't figure out why. it has to do with the mobile browser. it doesn't recognize clicking functionality unless the onlick attr is provided. but when the code resides IN the attr it also doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Oh okay I'll give it a try when I get home and let you know if you're trick works lol. Thanks

Comment: A little late of a response, but for some reason it just didn't want to work. So I just decided to drop the button on mobile since it was causing so many problems.